# Getting error 'Excon nonblock is not supported by your OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket' (Heroku)

Tags: heroku

When trying to push my app to Heroku, it is hanging and I get this message:

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

When running:

```
heroku status
```

I am getting the error:

```
Excon nonblock is not supported by your OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket
```

Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My company has blocked a ton of stuff so it has something to do with that. When I tried using my phone as a wifi hotspot it worked fine so it has something to do with my network connection at work.

Comment: My company is doing the same thing it seems. Any idea what they would be blocking to cause this issue?

Comment: Not sure- I realized that the network I accidentally was using that day actually blocks most sites other than Google and oddly Facebook, Twitter, etc.